# How can I create a new imovie theme (or customize an existing one)?

Tags: macos, imovie, themes

In imovie 10 (like in its predecessors) there are a bunch of nice themes. I've got a standard one I use almost all the time. There are some things I always change, though, like the wording of the closing title. And I'd like to show a small logo at the top of the screen during the start and end of the movie, for instance.

Now... this means customizing an existing theme. Or making a new one. Only... I cannot figure out how to do this. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

The themes are stored within the Application bundle itself, which is code signed, so even if you figure out how to modify them - the OS will not want to run the tampered application.

You might be better off with the Pro Version of the tool if you need to customize a theme and control or you might be able to [create the title and end sequences in Motion](https://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/motion/) and use iMovie for the rest of the editing. That's far less expensive than the Final Cut Pro price - but you can test drive that for free if you wish.

- https://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/